# Why is intel hex library printing 255 when reading from an HEX file and convert it to binary with tobinarray?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write content from a intel hex file to a microcontroller but when I convert the content from hex to binary with the method `tobinarray()` from the `intelHex` module and print it out, all bytes are 255, and that's not the content in the hex file when I open it in notepad++.

When I print the content using the `dump()` method it looks correct.
Anyone have an idea why it prints `255`?
I can also see that when I send some bytes over serial line to my microcontroller it receives only `255`.

```
from intelhex import IntelHex

hexFile = IntelHex("test.hex")
code = hexFile.tobinarray(start=0, size=9)
print(code)
```

The code gives this output:

```
array('B', [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
```

This is some content of the hex file, so it's obviously not something wrong in the hex file:

[image]

EDIT:
Figured out why it didn't work.
The parameters start (and end if specified) needs to be the exact addresses, which in my case was 0x8008000 (only 8000 is shown inside the hex file, which is the offset of the base address 0x800000).
By printing the min and/or max address with `print(hexFile.minaddr())` I was able to see that I needed to provide it as parameter to the method.
So the correct code should look something like this:

```
code = hexFile.tobinarray(start=0x8008000, size=16)
print(code)
```

output:

```
array('B', [0, 0, 2, 32, 177, 154, 0, 8, 33, 154, 0, 8, 35, 154, 0, 8])
```

which is the second line in the hex file, the black digits

Comment: Please post the hex file as _[formatted text](/help/formatting)_, not a screenshot, so that people can copy it to their computers to test your code. A [mre] is not reproducible if people need to transcribe the image of your input file.

Comment: You are printing out the contents of addresses 0 thru 8.  The HEX file doesn't *have* any contents in that range - its data lines cover the addresses from 0x8000 to 0x812F.  The module you're using considers the value of unspecified addresses to be 0xFF - which is reasonable, since various memory technologies (that HEX files would typically be used with) can have 1 bits turned into 0s directly, but the opposite transition requires a separate erase operation.

Comment: I tried with 0x8000 but it didn't work, until I realized I needed to provide the full address, see my edit above